# Not Getting option to change to manual SCIM Provisioning

Tags: azure, scim

How I can change the option of scim provisioning from automatic to manual in Azure ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enabled  only  when there is no automatic [`Azure AD provision connector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/user-provisioning#manual-vs-automatic-provisioning) available

> Manual provisioning means there is no automatic Azure AD provisioning
>   connector for the app yet. User accounts must be created manually, for
>   example by adding users directly into the app's administrative portal,
>   or uploading a spreadsheet with user account detail. Consult the
>   documentation provided by the app, or contact the app developer to
>   determine what mechanisms are available.